# Formatting strings in python with variables

Tags: python

So this is my code but it returns error like this "Unknown format code 'e' for object of type 'str'". why??

```
c="*"*i
e=input01
d="{:>e}"
print(d.format(c))
```

Comment: please write what you are trying to achieve? what is your code supposed to do?  what is the output you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Pass `e` into the format as a variable, you are simply using the string `"e"` hence the error:

```
d = "{:>{e}}"
print(d.format(c, e=e))
```

You can see actually passing the variable right adjusts the string correctly:

```
In [3]: c = "*" * 4    
In [4]: e = "10"    
In [5]: d = "{:>{e}}"    
In [6]: d.format(c, e=e)
Out[6]: '      ****'
```

You could also remove the e from the format and pass it as the second arg to format:

```
d = "{:>{}}"
print(d.format(c, e))
```

Either way the `{}` after `>` is essential.